# Conditions for monotone convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

I have a difference function of the form $ z_{t+1} = (1-\beta)z_t + \lambda(1-z_t) $ where $ 0 \leq z_0 \leq 1, 0 < \beta < 1 , 0 < \lambda < 1$. Find conditions such that the sequence ${z_t}$ converges in a monotone manner.

I can see that this sequence ${z_t}$ converges to $ \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \beta}$, but how do I find conditions which guarantee that the sequence converges in a monotone manner?

Comment: If A) $(1-\beta) \lt 1.0$ and B) $\lambda \lt 1.0$ and C) $0 \lt (1-\beta + \lambda) \lt 1$ then $z_{t+1} < z_{t} ~\forall t$. This implies that $z_{t}$ will converge monotonically to zero. There may be other less strict conditions that guarantee monotone convergence but those definitely ensure  it.

Comment: why can't ${z_t}$ be an increasing sequence in this case?

Comment: Hi: given the conditions in my comment, no matter what $z_{0}$ is initially, $ \forall t ~z_{t}$  cannot be greater than $z_{(t-1)}$. So, the sequence has to be monotonic decreasing. Try it out with some numbers because I think that's the best way to see it.

Comment: Note that there should be an analytic proof of your question. I couldn't prove it which is why I only used a comment.

Comment: there should be a way to use the roots of the characteristic equation associated with the difference equation being set to zero. If you're really interested, look at the derivation of garch(1,1) ( bollerslev's original paper ) because the same restriction , namely, $( 1 - \beta + \lambda)$,  is also used in there for the stationarity requirement of a garch(1,1).  So, assuming there's a proof for the stationarity of a garch(1,1) in there, then the same or a similar proof could probably be used here. It really depends on if you need a proof.

Comment: My apologies but you can mostly disregard the comments above. The first one is wrong about converging to zero and I also had the condition wrong but it still does monotonically decrease and converge to a constant. The other comments are mostly correct but the derivation is pretty straightforward so there's no need to look at the garch(1,1). Your model is very similar to an AR(1) in time-series analysis but I won't go into that in the answer. See answer below and my apologies for mistakes and noise. I can say with reasonable certainty ( LOL ) that below is correct.

Answer (score 1):

@sucksatmath: The difference equation:

[1] $~~~z_{t+1} = (1-\beta) \times z_{t} + \lambda \times (1-z_{t})$ can be re-written as

[2] $~~~z_{t+1} = (1 - \beta - \lambda) \times z_{t} + \lambda$.

( The relation above is very similar to the AR(1) with non-zero mean but I won't go into that here. See Hamilton's "Time Series Analysis" for a more detailed discussion).

Now, let L denote the lag operator, so that $L(x_{t+1}) = x_{t}$. Then, the previous difference equation can be re-written as

$z_{t+1} \times (1 - (1-\beta-\lambda)L) = \lambda$

Now, in order for the series, $\{z_t\}$, to converge to something pointwise, we write $z_{t+1}$ by itself and obtain

$z_{t+1} = \frac{\lambda}{(1-(1-\beta-\lambda)L)}$

Letting $\rho = (1-\beta-\lambda)$ just to simplify the notation, we have:

$z_{t+1} = \frac{\lambda}{(1- \rho L)}$

Notice that the RHS is an infinite geometric series in $\rho$. The lag operator L does not end up playing a role because $\lambda$ is not a function of time.

So, we can re-write the infinite geometric series without the lag operator. This results in:

$z_{t+1} = \frac{\lambda}{(1-\rho)} = \lambda \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \rho^{i}$. Obviously this converges as long as $0 \lt \rho \lt 1.0.$

In summary: Given the original conditions stated for $\lambda$ and $\beta$, if we add the condition that $ 0 \lt (1-\beta-\lambda) \lt 1.0$ then $z_{t+1}$ decreases monotonically to the limit $\frac{\lambda}{1-(1-\beta-\lambda)} = \frac{\lambda}{(\lambda + \beta)}$.

Finally, notice that the limiting value  is EXACTLY what you claimed it was in your original question so I apologize for that too.  I'm not clear how you obtained that but I'd be interested.

Notice that equation [2] illustrates ( "proves" if you will ) that the $z_{t}$ sequence  will be monotonic decreasing as long as the condition  $0 \lt (1-\beta-\lambda) \lt 1.0$ holds.

Comment: What does AR(1) stand for?

Comment: AR(1) stands for autoregressive time series with only one lag. So, in time series, the AR(1) would be: $x_t = \phi x_{t-1} + \mu + \epsilon_t$. So there is an error term , $\epsilon_t$, that doesn't show up in your difference equation relation but, other than that term, they are pretty much the same thing. In time series, the error term, $\epsilon_t$,  represents the difference between the realization and the expected value of the realization. In your equation, you don't need that term because it's a deterministic, rather than stochastic, process.

Comment: if you have an interest in time series and decent stat background, I recommend Hamilton's text.